# Can't create stored procedure with this code -- why?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server-2008

```
CREATE PROCEDURE NAMES  AS

NAME VARCHAR (20),
REGNO VARCHAR(100),

BEGIN
SELECT NAME=@NAME FROM  STUDENTDETAIL
SELECT REGNO=@REGNO FROM STUDENTDETAIL
END
```

why this stored procedure is not created?

Comment: why have you tagged with both mysql and sql server?

Comment: I originally answered this question, but there are so many things wrong with what you're doing, I'm not sure what your intention is.  Also, please list a single technology you're using (MySql and Microsoft SQL Server 2008 use different syntax).

Answer (score 1):

You

1. Forgot to name your variables correctly
2. Used incorrect syntax
3. Did some crazy selects... so I'll just be guessing from here on out:

in SQL Server 2008

```
CREATE PROCEDURE NAMES
(
NAME VARCHAR (20),
REGNO VARCHAR(100)
)
AS
  SELECT * FROM STUDENTDETAIL WHERE NAME=@NAME AND REGN=@REGNO;
GO
```

In MySQL

```
mysql> delimiter //

mysql> CREATE PROCEDURE NAMES (NAME VARCHAR (20), REGNO VARCHAR(100))
    -> BEGIN
    ->   SELECT * FROM STUDENTDETAIL WHERE NAME=@NAME AND REGN=@REGNO;
    -> END//
```

Comment: WE DON'T NEED TO USE BEGIN AND END COMMANDS AH?

Comment: @user1500707 are you mad?! anyway be more specific when adding tags because MySQL and MSSQL uses different syntax.

Comment: Begin/End commands are not required in SQL Server 2008.  I'm not intimately familiar with MySql and have always seen them included.

Comment: I'm not a MySQL person either but I seem to have always seen the delimiter restored to the standard `;` in the end. Anyway, that may not matter as the `mysql` tag may well have been added by mistake (it often is).